# Adding two 'next' and 'prev' links breaks scrollable plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I'm using the `scrollable` plugin from [jquerytools.org](http://jquerytools.org/), and I basically need to add a next and previous link at the top and the bottom of my page, but for some reason when I add a second pair of links, the scrollable feature breaks. I think the HTML tables might be the culprit here because I've been able to get it working using div elements, unfortunately I have to use the table structure like you see in my example below.

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/FJFuY/) (using one pair of next/prev links)

[broken example](http://jsfiddle.net/FJFuY/1) (using two pairs of next/prev links)

Any thing I can do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use scrollable api to use next and prev function please refer this links

http://jquerytools.org/documentation/scrollable/index.html
http://jquerytools.org/documentation/scripting.html

please refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FJFuY/3/) for reference